# Can't set Scrollview Header, Can't scroll when using datatemplate in scrollview

Tags: uwp-xaml

I want to use a dynamic header in a scrollviwer (tried other things, the scroll viewer works best for my application) but when I set the header it crashes. I've tried to set the content and the only way it doesn't crash is using a datatemplate inside the contenttemplate, but if I do that the content won't scroll! I'm simply doing this just for testing:

**Simple Scrollviewer Test**

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
        <Grid Width="800" Height="75" Background="Green"/>
    </ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
    <ScrollViewer.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
                <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ScrollViewer.ContentTemplate>
</ScrollViewer>
```

P.S. I've tried to put many different things in the template and wrap them in every layout option there is. Even a grid doesn't work.

Comment: Hey! you guys with the minus garbage. Try this, it doesn't work. before you say i haven't done my research try it. Or at least post an real usable answer. Paste what i posted in, doesn't scroll. If you can get it to scroll then tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to use a dynamic header in a scrollviwer (tried other things, the scroll viewer works best for my application) but when I set the header it crashes.

The problem is the [`LeftHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_LeftHeader), [`TopHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_TopHeader), and [`TopLeftHeader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ScrollViewer_TopLeftHeader) properties can be set only when `ScrollViewer` content's `HorizontalAlignment` is Left and `VerticalAlignment` is Top. So you need to modify your xaml like following:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
        <Grid Width="800" Height="75" Background="Green" />
    </ScrollViewer.TopHeader>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
        <TextBlock Text="hello" FontSize="75" />
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

For more, you could refer [ScrollViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer) official documentation.

Comment: I saw that in the MS documentation before I posted the question and tried it but it didn't work. I just tried it again and it worked! thanks so much!